# Assigning or inserting class objects in unordered_map

Tags: c++, class

I have a class: `class1` with a private member variable:

`std::unordered_map<std::string, class2> s_list;`

I am trying to insert or assign objects of `class2` in the above `s_list`.

The `class2` has a copy constructor of the form:

```
class2::class2(const class2& obj)
{
    x = obj.x;
    y = obj.y;
}
```

It also has another constructor:

```
class2::class2(std::string x1, double y1)
{
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
}
```

Inside one of the functions of `class1`, I have the following lines:

```
class2 s_obj(x1, y1);
s_list[x1] = s_obj;
```

However, it throws the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘class2::class2()’
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: As the error message says, you need a default constructor `class2::class2()`.  As you have a user-supplied one the default one is not generated.

Comment: you need a default ctor for class2 i.e class2::class2(){}

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation of [`std::unordered_map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) `s_list[x1]` inserts an element using a default constructor. Your class doesn't have one, hence it can't do that. Did you try using [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a default `ctor`. In an `unordered_map` if there is no match for a value of a `key` it creates a default one and returns a reference to it.

Consider the subscript operator `[]`.[See Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at). Closely observe the return `T&`

If you do `s_list["foo"]` and there is no `value` associated with "foo" it creates a entry in the unordered_map with `key` "foo" and returns a reference to the default value by callings its default ctor.

In your class2 you dont have one. To fix it create a default ctor

```
class class2 // horrible name btw
{
   class2() = default;
}
```

or use `insert`. [Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert)

Comment: How would you suggest solving the problem?

Comment: But shouldn't copy constructor take care of it in the absence of default constructor?

Comment: @skr_robo No, not really. The value is copied, after the element is created.

Comment: @skr_robo what Algirdas said the value is copied after. Create a default ctor and maybe do a getter/setter for the values or after the object is created use your copy ctor by assigning it a new object. Also I would consider storing pointers and not raw objects.

Comment: @skr_robo my bad fixed the link to See Here.

Comment: I would suggest against making a default constructor, if that doesn't make sense in particular use case (in addition to always preferring value-semantics instead of pointer-semantics), just so `std::unordered_map::operator[]` would work. What's wrong with using `std::unordered_map::insert` to insert values, that aren't default-constructible?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius nothing wrong I would prefer using a insert in this case.

Comment: @SamerTufail You say that now.. But your answer contradicts such statement.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It's actually collecting sensor data in a loop. The insert will give the wrong impression to someone who reads the code later. I got the job done by adding the default constructor.

Comment: @SamerTufail Thank You.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I answered based on the OP's  use case ... I added the reference to insert for completeness..

Comment: @skr_robo if it's in a loop; then the better function to call is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert_or_assign

Comment: @UKMonkey: I had never heard of that function. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way you can add items to the map without needing that constructor is to use the function `insert` rather than `[]`.

ie `s_list.insert({x1, s_obj})`

This is because (as the other answer states) `[]` returns a reference to the object that will be assigned (and must therefore be created); while insert will copy the objects passed to it without needing to create them first.

Update from other comments:
there also exists `insert_or_assign` which will assign the existing value to the new one if it exists; ie working in exactly the same way as `[]` does without calling the default constructor